# FFMPEG command in PHP shell_exec is too slow for a 300Mo mp4

Tags: php, ffmpeg, shell-exec

I have a web site where user upload videos.

When a video is uploaded I shell_exec 3 ffmpeg commands:

1. Generate preview:

   ```
   $cmd =  "ffmpeg -ss 1 -i ".$filePath." -vf \"scale='if(gt(dar,360/202),202*dar,360)':'if(gt(dar,360/202),202,360/dar)',setsar=1,crop=360:202\"  -frames:v 1 ".$thumbnail;
   ```
2. Compress the video:

   ```
   $cmd = "ffmpeg -i ".$filePath." -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast -c:a aac -ab 128k -movflags faststart ".$wmoutput;
   ```
3. Add watermark:

   ```
   $cmd = 'ffmpeg -i '.$wmoutput.' -i new/watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" '.$finaloutput;
   ```

The problem is that these 3 commands take a lot of time to finish and sometimes it goes over Maximum execution time specialy for video files that are bigger than 300Mo. I can just expand the Maximum execution time but I don't know how many seconds I have to set.

Is there a way to make the scripts above execute faster without having to change the Maximum execution time?

Comment: What parameters server you have? It has nothing to do with PHP speed, but more with how powerful your server is. Also make it as CLI background command to get rid of execution timeout

Comment: you should employ some sort of async processing/scheduled tasks like cron or gearman.

Comment: Processor
4 Core
Memory
8 GB
Disc
200 GB SSD
BANDWIDTH
Trafic
200 Mb/s

Comment: What do you mean by async? please note that it is important to me that these commands execute right after the upload.

Comment: @nopapi CRONs shouldn't have execution time limitation. 1. Change script so it moves files to a temporary directory. 2. Move these commands to a CRON that runs every minute on all files in temporary directory and then move them to final destination.

Answer (score 0):

Combine *Compress the video* and *add watermark* into one command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i new/watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast -c:a aac -ab 128k -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

Should be significantly faster and you avoid yet another instance of [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).

Comment: It worked. I also added a function that execut the command in the background.

function BGexec($cmd){
 if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
  pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
 }
 else {
  exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
 }
}